# Search for a value in List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, list, search, .net-4.0, dictionary

I have a `List< Dictionary < string, object >>` variable as follows.

```
private static List<Dictionary<string, object>> testData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(100);

// Just Sample data for understanding.
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var test = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "aaa", "aaa" + i % 4 },
            { "bbb", "bbb" + i % 4 },
            { "ccc", "ccc" + i % 4 },
            { "ddd", "ddd" + i % 4 },
            { "eee", "eee" + i % 4 },
            { "fff", "fff" + i % 4 },
            { "ggg", "ggg" + i % 4 },
            { "hhh", "hhh" + i % 4 },
            { "iii", "iii" + i % 4 }
        };
    testData.Add(test);
}
```

I want to search for a list of key,value in the Dictionary and return the `List< Dictionary < string, object >>` contains the searchPattern I passed.

```
Dictionary<string, object> searchPattern = new Dictionary<string, object>();
searchPattern .Add("aaa", "aaa4");
searchPattern .Add("eee", "eee2");
searchPattern .Add("fff", "fff1");
searchPattern .Add("ddd", "ddd3");


public List<Dictionary<string, object>> SearchList(List<Dictionary<string, object>> testData, Dictionary<string, object> searchPattern)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result;

    // Search the list.

    return result;
}
```

Any other suggestions to search also appreciated.
Many Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What would be the expected output for your example?

Comment: What result you expect to return?

Comment: @veredesmarald, @ Cuong Le: In  the 100 rows in the list , I want to search for the row which contains all the key value pairs "aaa", "aaa4" & "eee", "eee2" & "fff", "fff1" & "ddd", "ddd3" and return that alone.

Comment: None of the dictionaries in your test data contain all of those key-value pairs.

Comment: When I see stuff like this I think, hmmm, that's doable but I have a feeling you're doing something wrong in the first place.

Comment: @veredesmarald: It's just a test data. My original data will contains some match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the first dictionary in the list that contains all the key-value pairs in search pattern, or `null` if there isn't one.

```
public Dictionary<string, object> SearchList
(
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> testData,
    Dictionary<string, object> searchPattern
)
{
    return testData.FirstOrDefault(x => searchPattern.All(x.Contains));
}
```

If you want all the matches (not just the first one) use `Where([...]).ToList()` instead of `FirstOrDefault([...])`.

Comment: @RameshDurai Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer? As far as I can tell it does the same thing as the other answer you accepted afterwards, but is cleaner?

Comment: Yes. Your answer was working. But It's returned only First value, I expected all datas. Where([...]).ToList() should work.

Comment: @RameshDurai I used `FirstOrDefault` because your comment says "I want to search for the row which contains all the key value pairs [...] and return that alone"... alone != a list of things.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. In the question I mentioned clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try:

```
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> SearchList(List<Dictionary<string, object>> testData, Dictionary<string, object> searchPattern)
    {
        return testData.Where(t =>
            {
                bool flag = true;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> p in searchPattern)
                {
                    if (!t.ContainsKey(p.Key) || !t[p.Key].Equals(p.Value))
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return flag;
            }).ToList();

    }
```

OR

```
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> SearchList(List<Dictionary<string, object>> testData, Dictionary<string, object> searchPattern)
    {
        return testData
                  .Where(t => searchPattern.All(p => t.ContainsKey(p.Key) && 
                                                     t[p.Key].Equals(p.Value)))
                  .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to unaccept your answer. Since @veredesmarald answer also working and he is the first one to answer I accepted his. Hope you will agree.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
var result = testData.Where(dic => searchPattern.All(dic.Contains))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm expecting the result of type List<Dictionary<string, object>> but it's returning IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.

Comment: @RameshDurai: Okay, what's data in each dictionary in result you need?

Comment: Please check the answers of veredesmarald and Konstantin Vasilcov.

Comment: @RameshDurai: I still don't understand what result you expect? folowing veredesmarald, the result is Zero?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16622/discussion-between-ramesh-durai-and-cuong-le)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of doing this.
   _Individuals1 = file1.fileIndividuals; 
        _Individuals2 = file2.fileIndividuals;

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Individual> kvpInd in _Individuals1) 
    { 
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Individual> kvpInd2 in _Individuals2) 
        { 
            if (kvpInd.Value.name.name == kvpInd2.Value.name.name) 
            { 
                similarInds.Add(kvpInd.Key, kvpInd.Value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

var similarInds = file1.fileIndividuals. 
Where(kv1 => file2.fileIndividuals.Any(kv2 => kv1.Value.name.name == kv2.Value.name.name)). 
ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

this will fail if you have duplicate values using linq you can do like this

Answer (score 0):

I agree with armen.shimoon, however something like this:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> SearchList(this List<Dictionary<string, object>> list,
        Dictionary<string, object> searchPattern)
    {
        return list.Where(item =>
            searchPattern.All(x => item.ContainsKey(x.Key) && 
                x.Value.Equals(item[x.Key])
            )).ToList();
    }
```

And then using like this:

```
    searchResult = testData.SearchList(searchPattern);
```

Comment: Don't you think that this answer has already been mentioned earlier?...and not even once