# Search in Dictionary Array C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary array like below:

```
(Dictionary<string, object>[])
```

Each dictionary in the array contain two keys "name" and "val" and and their associated values.

How can I search for a particular "name" e.g. test and return the "val".

Comment: Its a list or array of dictionaries and every dictionary in the list contains two keys. I tried selectmany but it simply flattened the collection to ienumerable.

Comment: What is the issue with `SelectMany`? Your question doesn't show the usage of this method

Comment: How did you get this?  It looks like it might have come from JSON, but the name/value pairs are consistent and should have been deserialized to typed objects, not dictionaries. Then you could search the array using the object's properties. Either way, what have you tried?  A loop?  LINQ?  Anything?

Comment: used code similar to this one and the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399212/search-for-a-value-in-listdictionarystring-object. basically I am parsing a TOML file and getting this list of dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "name" is unique across all the dictionaries:

```
var val = dictionaries.SingleOrDefault(d=> d.ContainsKey("name")).?["name"];
```

If "name" is present in multiple dictionaries:

```
var vals = dictionaries.Where(d=> d.ContainsKey("name")).Select(d => d["name"]);
```

Comment: I used similar solution like yours: var vals = dictionaries.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Values.Contains("someValue"))["correspondingKey"];

Comment: `d.Values.Contains` is probably very slow; it defeats most of the sense in using a dictionary if you're going to loop through its values collection looking for a value, and then get the key. You'd be better flipping your dictionary around so what was the value is now the key and vice versa