# Search for a value in List<Dictionary<string, object>> but using a non specific string

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, search

Is there is a way to search in `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` with a non specific string, like the `LIKE OPERATION(%)` in SQL and return the new `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

I found this stuff, but it uses a specific string to search.
[Search for a value in List<Dictionary<string, object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399212/search-for-a-value-in-listdictionarystring-object)

For example, I have a list Dictionary like this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> userList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(){
    new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        {"Id", 1},
        {"Name", "John"}
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        {"Id", 2},
        {"Name", "Foo"}
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        {"Id", 3},
        {"Name", "Admin"}
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        {"Id", 4},
        {"Name", "AdminAccount"}
    },
}
```

If the user want to search a string "Jo", then he/she can get the first list with "John" name. But if the search string is "Admin", then first two last Dictionary will return.

Actually, this is achievable using loop. But I want to learn how to use LINQ to make my codes shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact you want to search the values and not the keys I think you can do this using System.Linq (add that as a using statement):

```
var filteredList = listOfDictionaries.Where(dictionary => dictionary.Values.Any(Value => Value.ToString().Contains(search))).ToList();
```

However, as your dictionary has the values as type 'object' will they always have an expected string representation?

UPDATE:

If you want to search only keys of a particular type you can do this.

```
var searchPair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "searchTerm");
var filteredList = listOfDictionaries.Where(dictionary => dictionary[searchPair.Key].ToString().Contains(searchPair.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: I have an error, "Does not contain a definition for Where."

Comment: @John You need to include `using System.Linq;` so that you can use the LINQ extension methods. `.FindAll` (as in your sample) isn't LINQ - it's a `List<T>` method.

Comment: it seems to be important to use the key `"Name"` in the dictionary. Otherwise you might find a match in an unrelated key and falsely include the wrong dictionary

Comment: Will it not search for entire Values of the Dictionary? Because I have many keys in the dictionary, maybe I will take much time.

Comment: @JohnArnoldBarrozo - updated to now only search the values of particular keys.